# Nested Array Map

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, nested, mapping

```
class Array extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            newArray: [
                  {
                    "Category": "Category1",
                    "value": [
                      {
                        "Name": "Name1"
                      },
                      {
                        "Name": "Name2"
                      },
                      {
                        "Name": "Name4"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "Category": "Category2",
                    "value": [
                      {
                        "Name": "Name3"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ],
        };
    }

  render() {
    var nestedArray = this.state.newArray.map((title, index) => {
      return(
        <div key={`nestedArray_${index}`}>
          <div key={`category_${title}`}>{title.Category}</div>
        </div>
      )
    })

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{nestedArray}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Array />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Codepen for current code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GePyBa

I have it displaying like this currently:

> **Category1**
>
> **Category2**

Ideally, I want it to be:

> **Category1**
>
> Name1
>
> Name2
>
> Name4
>
> **Category2**
>
> Name3

I've tried searching for answers, but nothing has really worked.

I tried doing something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
 render() {
    var innerArray = this.state.newArray.map((values) => {
      return {this.state.newArray.value[values].map((name, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={`value_${name}`}>{name.Name}</div>
        )
      })}
    })
    var nestedArray = this.state.newArray.map((title, index) => {
      return(
        <div key={`nestedArray_${index}`}>
          <div key={`category_${title}`}>{title.Category}</div>
          {innerArray}
        </div>
      )
    })

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{nestedArray}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

New to Javascript and React, so I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `map` on each `value` array in every `title` object as well to render all the `Name` properties.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    newArray: [
      {
        Category: "Category1",
        value: [
          {
            Name: "Name1"
          },
          {
            Name: "Name2"
          },
          {
            Name: "Name4"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        Category: "Category2",
        value: [
          {
            Name: "Name3"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    var nestedArray = this.state.newArray.map((title, index) => {
      return (
        <div key={index}>
          <h1>{title.Category}</h1>
          {title.value.map((val, index) => (
            <div key={index}>{val.Name}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>
        {nestedArray}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Tholle works. I just want to add that do not name your component as `Array`. It will throw errors thinking you are modifying JavaScript's in-built `Array` object.

That is why in your codepen example, even if you map on nested `value`, it throws `TypeError: Class constructor Array cannot be invoked without 'new'` error.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. I didn't really name the component Array. It was just there as a placeholder.